# How do you use a class as a name space, when transpiling JavaScript using Google's Closure?

Tags: javascript, class, google-closure-compiler

I'm adapting some JavaScript code to be transpiled in Google's Closure, using `ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS`. I'm using a `class` as a namespace:

```
class MySpiffyClass {
    ...
}
```

The class contains methods and static "fields", including many other classes. Everything in the .js file is contained inside this class. Looking forward, there will be ~10 other .js files, each of which contains its own class in a similar manner. HTML documents might use one or several of these files, and I have no control over which ones are used. I don't want any of them to interfere with each other--hence the need for namespaces.

When I transpile, I see no reference to my class `MySpiffyClass` in the resulting code. I have to assume that Closure isn't following my wishes. I've tried adding `export` to my class definition line, but it didn't seem to have any effect. Any help would be appreciated--I'm new to Closure, and most of the docs don't make any reference to using classes in one's code.

Addendum--here's a minimal version of the file `demo.js`:

```
class MySpiffyClass {
    static go() {
        window.alert("we're running! " + MySpiffyClass.someValue);
    }
}

MySpiffyClass.someValue = 3;
window.addEventListener('load', MySpiffyClass.go, false);
```

And the HTML file to run it:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Basic Demo</title>
        <script src="demo.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <p>Hello.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't use a class as a namespace. Use a plain object literal if you must. But with ES6 modules, hierarchical module names should suffice for namespaces.

Comment: There are many other aspects to the class that I'm taking advantage of--especially adding methods in a clean, readable way, and being able to think of my code in an object-oriented fashion.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the compiler output and also to know which compiler flags you have used.

Answer (score 1):

> When I transpile, I see no reference to my class MySpiffyClass in the resulting code.

This sounds like the compiler has mangled all the names which can happen in advanced compilation mode if you didn't provide an externs file.

Here's the smallest reproducible case I can think of:
*(`cc` is just an alias to invoke my compiler.)*

```js
// tmp/repro.js
window.MySpiffyClass = class {}
```

```
bash-5.0# cc --compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS --language_in ECMASCRIPT_NEXT --js tmp/repro.js
window.g=function(){};
```

You can see that compiler has mangled the class name.

You can avoid this with an externs file which is a list of symbols that the compiler should not rename:

```js
// tmp/externs.js
var MySpiffyClass;
```

```
bash-5.0# cc --compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS --language_in ECMASCRIPT_NEXT --js tmp/repro.js --externs tmp/externs.js 
window.MySpiffyClass=function(){};
```

Comment: I think that this is what I want to achieve. But I've tried several permutations of this, with various Javadoc-appearing comments. Doing it the way you have here, I get this:

ERROR - [JSC_VAR_MULTIPLY_DECLARED_ERROR] Variable MySpiffyClass declared more than once. First occurrence: externs.js.

(This is when my externs.js has just one line, which is the var line as you have above. There are no special comments or decorators on the class in my main js file.)

Comment: That error can happen if you do something like `class Foo {} … window.Foo = Foo` — or you literally have the same class name in a different file. It's hard to tell without seeing more of your files.

Comment: I've added minimal code in the description.

There's something about extern that I'm missing. It looks to me like you've just double declared something, via your line `var MySpiffyClass`. That's exactly the error it's giving.

Comment: @AdamSmith The externs file should not be passed in a `--js` flag. If you do that would count as a duplicate variable declaration indeed. Instead the externs file should be passed via `--externs`. Any chance we could have a look at your GCC flags?

Comment: Yes, I understand that I'm using the --externs flag rather than --js, but that doesn't seem to make a difference. It thinks that something is being double-declared. Also--apologies--I don't know what a GCC flag is. For my transpiler, I'm just running `java -jar /usr/share/java-myjars/closure.jar ...`. Nothing fancy.

Comment: `closure --compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS --externs externs-demo.js --js demo.js`, where externs-demo.js contains the single line `var MySpiffyClass;`.